# Selecting an option by its value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to run this jQuery selector:

```
$("#label option[value=\"newLabel\"]")
```

On the following code:

```
<select name="label" id="label"> 
    <option value="1" label="testLabel">testLabel</option> 
    <option value="newLabel" label="New Label">New Label</option> 
</select>
```

But the selector just won't find it - can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes in the selector, i.e.:

```
$("#label option[value=newLabel]")
```

Comment: If that works for you I suspect this is a browser bug then. I'm running Chrome on Ubuntu and that doesn't change the value. I'll try it in FF.

Comment: You probably want to put it in quotes: `$("#label option[value='newLabel']")` if you are having trouble with it.